# What are some good resource monitoring frameworks or techniques for third party services?

Tags: resources, monitoring

In our software, we use many third party applications, services and databases.  We have no control over these applications but would like to do our own health checks on these services and be notified if anything goes down (email, wallboard).  Note that these services are mostly in our internal network and not publicly visible.

- An arbitrary case would be to send a SOAP request, get the response back and analyze the XML output, looking for the word 'success'.
- Another case would be to send a request, expect a 302 and look at the redirect location.
- And yet another case would be to simply ping a hostname.

In all of these cases, if something out of the ordinary happens, an alert email could be sent out.  There could also be a web-view on these status checks to display on a large TV monitor.

What kind of arrangement do you have to monitor your dependencies?

One idea that we've got is to write single web pages that do the actual check and return a status code of 200 or 500.  We'd then need some kind of tool to query these pages we've written and alert us if it's a 500 being returned.